# Unable to run systemd inside docker which is being run inside jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, systemd

**I'm trying to get Jenkins to run Docker that runs SystemD**.

So far **I've been able to run systemd inside docker locally without Jenkins**. Here are the steps to run it locally without jenkins:

```
# pull unop/fedora-systemd and create and run the container for it
sudo docker run --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -e container=docker --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /tmp -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -t -i unop/fedora-systemd

# on a different terminal window, I can:
# get the container id of the "unop/fedora-systemd" image
sudo docker ps

# then exec bash on it
sudo docker container exec -t -i a98aa2bcd19e bash # where a98aa2bcd19e is the container id found above

# once inside the container, I can run systemd without any problems. examples:
systemctl status
systemctl start dbus.service
systemctl status dbus.service
```

The above works locally and I am able to run systemd inside the docker container.
The problem I get is when I try the same thing, but inside Jenkins.

I've tried to tweak Jenkinsfile several times, but not of my previous tries seemed to work. I always get an **error when running under Jenkins** similar to this:

```
+ systemctl status
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

This is my latest **Jenkinsfile** that I've tried

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'unop/fedora-systemd'
            args '--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -e container=docker --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /tmp -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -t -i'
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                sh "echo hello world"
                sh "systemctl status"
                sh "systemctl start dbus.service"
                sh "systemctl dbus.service"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On previous iterations of the Jenkinsfile, I've tried to replace `-cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -e container=docker` for `--privileged`, but that didn't help, I still got the same errors

**Anyone have an idea of how can I get this to work? Why does the above work locally, but not on Jenkins? what am I missing here?**

Note: Jenkins version: 2.150.2 and this is the **Dockerfile** used by *unop/fedora-systemd*

```
FROM fedora:rawhide
MAINTAINER http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Cloud

ENV container docker

RUN dnf -y update && dnf clean all

RUN dnf -y install systemd && dnf clean all && \
(cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;

VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup", "/tmp", "/run" ]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

PS: I've seen a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053483/how-to-enable-systemd-service-in-openshift-jenkins-1-centos7-docker-container), but what they were asking is different

Comment: The information in the following article might be useful: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/09/13/running-systemd-in-a-non-privileged-container/. It is a follow-up article to an earlier one that originally suggested some things similar to your `unop/fedora-systemd` snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I did not know about the related question. Let me point out again that you do not need to run a systemd daemon in a systemd controlled container if it is just about running multiple services in it. Simply overwrite `/usr/bin/systemctl` with the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) script. Then go to register it with `CMD ["/usr/bin/systemctl"]` as the init process of the container.

That's it. Now you can run any systemctl-start process from the operating system. It works to the extent that even provisioning with ansible/puppet scripts have no problem at all. An specficially, I am using that to provision Jenkins images with the operating system that the developers like to have as a basis. No priviledged mode required.

Answer (score 0):

You may try an image that has Fedora with System D already active with this command:

`docker run -d --name systemd-fedora --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro jrei/systemd-fedora`

Then you just need to run:

`docker exec -it systemd-fedora /bin/bash`

and there you can just install, start and restart any service you need.